# Как узнать название программы по пункту меню?

Tags: linux

Например, чтобы открыть Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor, я ввожу в терминале просто inkscape.

Как мне узнать такие названия у других программ?

Comment: В документации.

Comment: встречный вопрос, а откуда ты узнал название «Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor»?

Comment: Такие название это "Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor" или "inkscape"?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в меню прочитал. это ж очевидно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, отнюдь... конечно это был ожидаемый ответ, но мало ли где-ещё можно было увидеть, может в синаптике, может ещё где... так что решил уточнить прежде чем тратить время на хороший ответ ;)

Answer (score 4):

#### короткий ответ:

можете воспользоваться вот таким скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "usage: $0 search string"; exit 1; }
d=${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}
h=${XDG_DATA_HOME:-${HOME}/.local/share}
a=${d}:${h}:
s=${a//://applications }
f="$@"
find ${s} -type f -name \*.desktop 2>/dev/null | \
  xargs grep -li "${f}" | xargs grep '^Exec'
```

пример использования с примером результата (регистр искомой строки не важен):

```
$ bash файл-с-этим-скриптом inkscape vector
Exec=inkscape %F
Exec=inkscape
```

#### длинный ответ с объяснениями:

то, что вы видите в меню, формируется из файлов с суффиксом `.desktop`, которые разыскиваются, согласно [стандарту](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), в каталогах:

```
$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications
$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications
```

если такие переменные окружения не определены, надо использовать:

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/.local/share/
```

двоеточием, как обычно принято в *unix*, разделяются каталоги при помещении нескольких в одну переменную.

---

т.е., надо найти файлы (чтобы не усложнять, исходим из того, что вышеупомянутые переменные не определены):

```
$ find {/usr/share,/usr/local/share,~/.local/share}/applications/ -type f -name \*.desktop 2>/dev/null
```

затем выбрать из списка те файлы, в которых упоминается искомая строка (к примеру, `Inkscape Vector`):

```
$ ... | xargs grep -l 'Inkscape Vector'
```

а затем вывести из отобранных файлов строки, начинающиеся с `Exec` (именно в этих строках написано, что именно следует запускать при щелчке по пункту меню):

```
$ ... | xargs grep '^Exec'
```

---

после соединения в одну строку получилась вот такая длинная команда:

```
$ find {/usr/share,/usr/local/share,~/.local/share}/applications/ -type f -name \*.desktop 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -l 'Inkscape Vector' | xargs grep '^Exec'
```

у меня в системе она выдала две строки:

```
Exec=inkscape %F
Exec=inkscape
```

из них, надеюсь, очевидно, что выполняться должна программа `inkscape`.

---

p.s. по локализованным именам (например: `Редактор векторной графики`) тоже отлично ищет:

```
$ find {/usr/share,/usr/local/share,~/.local/share}/applications/ -type f -name \*.desktop 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -l 'Редактор векторной графики' | xargs grep '^Exec'
Exec=inkscape %F
Exec=inkscape
```

Comment: я бы добавил, что в большинстве DE под правой кнопкой мыши в меню есть пункт «редактировать», который запускает гуёвый редактор этого самого `.desktop`-файла, где можно посмотреть команду без лишних телодвижений...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я не пользуюсь ни одним de, потому даже проверить не могу. потому лучше воздержусь. напишите свой вариант ответа, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

> Как узнать название программы по пункту меню?

Это зависит от дистрибутива Linux. Но, по любому, у Вас есть некий аналог виндовозной кнопки "Пуск". Нажав на которую Вы и получаете меню.  И далее, два варианта:

1. В выпавшем меню где-то есть пункт, который называется как-то вроде "Редактировать главное меню"
2. Щёлкнув правой клавишей мышки по этой кнопке, Вы увидите контекстное меню, в котором будет пункт "Редактировать меню"

Либо первым, либо вторым способом запускаете редактор меню, находите нужный Вам пункт, открываете его свойства и видите имя запускаемого модуля.

Кстати, вариант изучением ярлыков на рабочем столе (файлы *.desktop) не очень хорош, так как в меню есть куча пунктов для запуска программ, у которых нет никаких ярлыков.

Comment: все пункты в меню для запуска программ в конечном итоге представлены desktop-файлами. Это стандарт freedesktop.org и AFAIK на сегодня не осталось DE, которые этому не подчиняются.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно как в `Windows`, все программы имеют свой исполяемый файл. В папке с установленной программой Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor лежит файлик `inkscape`, который и запускается. Запустить его можно просто указав полный путь до него.

Чтобы не задавать полные пути, можно поместить ссылки на исполняемые файлы в каталоги `/bin` и `/sbin` (а так же их варианты для пользоваетля `/usr/bin` и `/usr/sbin`). Тогда можно вызывать файлы просто написав inkscape и Linux сам найдет исполняемый файл.

Можно самому прописывать пути в Bash, примерно как это делается в `Windows` через `Path`, только другим механизмом.

В любом случае когда вы ставите пакет, вы не знаете куда он помещает свое содержимое и как называются исполняемые файлы, поэтому лучше искать в документацие.